# Imgur API: 404 not found responses when photo does not belong to user's account

Tags: python, json, api, rest, imgur

When I request images by hash from the imgur API I consistently get a 404 not found response, unless I supply a hash of an image uploaded to my personal account, then I receive a proper response. What may be the reason for that? Is there any way you can think of solving this? Thank you

```
header = {"Authorization": f"Client-ID {CLIENT_ID}"}

url1 = https://api.imgur.com/3/image/OhHNMos
request1 = requests.get(url1, headers=header)
print(request1.status_code) # 200

url2 = https://api.imgur.com/3/image/iFp46tO
request2 = requests.get(url2, headers=header)
print(request2.status_code) # 404
```

Comment: Having a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution?